# How to run AlpineJS with TailwindCSS both in watch mode in Vite

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

### Background

I tried using AlpineJS standalone. Then when I tried using other solutions as a node_module they didn't work in combination or require too much tweak/setup. So I went with Vite installing AlpineJS. Then added TailwindCSS and other required packages. They all work seamlessly in combination, and I was happy until I started progressing with this setup.

### Problem

When using Vite, I had to run `npm run dev` to run and watch the server. But Tailwind also has its own `watch` command. When I run `npm run dev` it doesn't run the Tailwind's command. So I opened two terminal tabs and ran both the commands in watch mode. But changing the Tailwind classes doesn't show any impact on my design, though the TailwindCSS watch mode was building simultaneously.

The issue is:
 **TailwindCSS is not building during Vite watch mode**

### Failed Workaround

I tried all that I could, including trying StackOverflow solutions, ChatGPT, and Gemini. Here are some of them:

#### Using Two Different Terminals

I ran two different terminals or terminal tabs for running the processes concurrently, they both work individually, but I did not see any changes on the TailwindCSS designs.

#### Using `&&`

I tried concatenating the commands in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite && tailwind:watch", //
  "build": "vite build && tailwind:build",
  "preview": "vite preview",
  "tailwind:watch": "tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/app.css -o ./dist/assets/css/app.min.css --watch",
  "tailwind:build": "tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/app.css -o ./dist/assets/css/app.min.css"
},
```

#### Using `concurrently`

I tried [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) and changed my `dev` command into this:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run vite\" && \"npm run tailwind:watch\"", //
  "tailwind:watch": "tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/app.css -o ./dist/assets/css/app.min.css --watch",
},
```

#### Force Delete Vite cache

I learned that Vite has a caching system that can be purged by using `--force` param with the `vite` command, so I tried with no luck:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run vite --force\" && \"npm run tailwind:watch\"", //
  "tailwind:watch": "tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/app.css -o ./dist/assets/css/app.min.css --watch",
},
```

### Solution❓

The only solution (?) I got that when changing any TailwindCSS class into the code:

1. Stop Vite
2. Run TailwindCSS build
3. Re-Run Vite again

But, why on earth they don't work in combination?

## Edit

### With PostCSS alternative

With Ihar's suggestion, I tried using PostCSS for Tailwind but stuck with `postcss.config.js`. The following code:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

Gave error:

```
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: C:/Users/Foo/TRYOUTS/myproject): [ReferenceError] module is not defined in ES module scope
```

So I tried:

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [tailwindcss({}), autoprefixer({})],
};
```

The same error persists.

The only suggestion for resolving the issue is to use Babel. Is that?

Comment: Use Tailwind as [PostCSS plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss). Dev command should be just `vite` (no need to run tailwindcss)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Updated my question with your suggestion

Comment: Try to change `module.exports =` into `export default`

Comment: The module error is gone, thanks for that. But no luck with the build things. My `tailwind.config.js` file's content is: `content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,js}"],` and I am expecting changes based on `./index.html`, and it's not compiling with `npm run dev`. :'(

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but at least I don't have to stop and start the server every time I change the Tailwind CSS classes.

I made a `vite.config.js` file in the root with the following content:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { version } from "./package.json";

const hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name].js?v=${hash}`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name].js?v=${hash}`,
        assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]?v=${hash}`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

With this in root directory, I ran two terminals/tabs, one running:

```bash
npm run dev
```

and the other running:

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/app.css -o ./dist/assets/css/app.min.css --watch
```

Now every time I change in `./index.html` the Tailwind builds itself on one terminal. And to trigger the other terminal (Vite) I just open the `package.json` and hit save, and that triggers the Vite restart and that's how the Tailwind's changes came into view.

At least I don't need to stop & start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your setup but having this app structure

```
app.css
index.html
index.js
vite.config.js
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg-blue-300 text-white font-bold p-4">
      My app is working
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Install TailwindCSS and Autoprefixer, init `tailwind.config.js`, fill in `content`

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './index.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

// postcss.config.js

export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

app.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

index.js

```js
// Don't use CSS as extra Tailwind entrypoint, just import it in JS
// or configure vite input options to be both js and css files (not html)
import './app.css'

// Alpine magic
// @link https://alpinejs.dev/
```

Package.json script "dev" is just "vite"

```json
"scripts": {
   "dev": "vite"
},
```

Run `npm run dev`

Every utility change from Tailwind should be updated